# Webview moves up when keyboard hides

Tags: android, webview, android-softkeyboard

The issue happens in an application whith a linear layout that divides the screen in two parts, the upper part is a simple View and the lower part is a WebView that loads google.com. The WebView takes the 60% of the space and the View the other 40%. In that scenario I touch the google search bar showing the soft keyboard, inmediately I touch the WebView outside the search bar just at the right of the search button, that hides the soft keyboard but just before this the WebView moves up for an instant and comes back to its initial position as the keyboard dissapears, no idea of why this happens and how to avoid it.

Please see the sample application, to reproduce the issue you can use a WVGA (800×480) simulator, I noticed the issue in a Samsung Galaxy Tab 10.1.
http://www.fileserve.com/file/txC3RV6/WebViewDemo.rar

Any suggestion?
Thanks for your time.
Goyo.

Answer (score 0):

If you put the entire linear view inside the scrollview then the webview wont move up.

Comment: Scrolling wont be possible if you put ScrollView around a LinearLayout which has WebView, WebView has already a scrolling mechanism.Never use ScrollView for WebView, it runs perfectly in the simulator but on the device you wont be able to sroll at all. hope this helps you.

Comment: Sniper thanks for answering, I tried what you suggested and it didn't work.